# Call to undefined relationship [role] on model [App\Employee]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to show roles assigined to employees using eloquent many-to-many relations but it says: Call to undefined relationship [role] on model [App\Employee]. i have applied lot of solutions from net but no one is working for me

```
  public function index()
  {
    $employees = Employee::with('role')->get();
    return view('relations.many-to-many.employee.index', compact('employees'));

   @foreach($employees as $employee)
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    {{ $employee->employee_name }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{ $employee->role->role_name }}
                  </td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

model employee

```
   public function roles()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_employee');
    }
```

model role

```
  public function employees()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(employee::class, 'role_employee');
  }
```

employees migration

```
  Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('employee_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

roles

```
 Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('role_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

role_employee

```
    Schema::create('role_employee', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('employee_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Can you write your modal code here

Comment: Its actually `roles`

Comment: @binadam, check my answer

Comment: @ZainFarooq where is mistake

Comment: You have defined the function name as `roles` but inside controller you are using it as `role`

Comment: maybe stupid, but you defined relationship `roles` not `role`, probably that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakenly used `role` instead of `roles`

```
$employees = Employee::with('roles')->get();
@foreach($employees as $employee)
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{ $employee->employee_name }}
              </td>
              <td>
               @foreach($employee->roles as $role)
               {{$role->role_name}}
               @endforeach
              </td>

            </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Update**
Change pivot table name from role_employee to employee_role and then refresh your migrations.

**Update 2**
Employee roles are collection so it should be inside foreach loop

Comment: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.employee_role' doesn't exist (SQL: select `roles`.*, `employee_role`.`employee_id` as `pivot_employee_id`, `employee_role`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `employee_role` on `roles`.`id` = `employee_role`.`role_id` where `employee_role`.`employee_id` in (4, 5, 6, 7))

Comment: Have you removed the foreign keys?

Comment: Property [role_name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Capitalize your first latter of employee here `return $this->belongsToMany(employee::class, 'role_employee');`

Comment: capitalized it plz check the updated question with migrations

Comment: Try change pivot table name from `role_employee` to `employee_role` and then refresh your migrations

Comment: I don't know but are your class name's first latter capital?

Comment: public function employees()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class, 'role_employee');
    }

Comment: Your pivot table name isn't according the standards of laravel. Change it as I have commented above

Comment: public function roles()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_employee');
    }

Comment: changed but this error is not removing Property [role_name] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Test my updated answer. I hope you will fix it. Earlier I mistakenly misspelled  `$role` as `$rola`

Comment: Great. Its nice to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First  change query as per your relationship name :

```
$employees = Employee::with('roles')->get();
```

As you have many-to-many relationship, one employee can have many roles,
change your code as below in your view

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
<tr>
  <td>
    {{ $employee->employee_name }}
  </td>
  <td>
    @foreach($employees->roles as $role)
      {{ $role->role_name }} <br>
    @endforeach
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Edit :** Update your modal as below
 Employee Model

```
 public function roles(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_employee','employee_id','role_id');
    }
```

Role Model

```
 public function employees() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class,'role_employee','role_id','employee_id');
    }
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.employee_role' doesn't exist (SQL: select `roles`.*, `employee_role`.`employee_id` as `pivot_employee_id`, `employee_role`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `employee_role` on `roles`.`id` = `employee_role`.`role_id` where `employee_role`.`employee_id` in (4, 5, 6, 7))

Comment: do you have this table : employee_role

Comment: role_employee chk the question

Answer (score 0):

you've defined `roles` method as in relationship and accesing `role`

Try this.

```
$employees = Employee::with('roles')->get();


@foreach($employees as $employee)
  <tr>
     <td>
         {{ $employee->employee_name }}
     </td>
     <td>
         {{ implode(', ', $employee->roles->pluck('role_name ')->toArray()) }}
     </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Model Employee**

```
public function roles(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_employee','employee_id','role_id');
}
```

**Model Role**

```
public function employees() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class,'role_employee','role_id','employee_id');
}
```

Comment: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.employee_role' doesn't exist (SQL: select roles.*, employee_role.employee_id as pivot_employee_id, employee_role.role_id as pivot_role_id from roles inner join employee_role on roles.id = employee_role.role_id where employee_role.employee_id in (4, 5, 6, 7)

Comment: class Employee extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
  'employee_name'
 ];

    public function roles()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_employee');
    }
}

Comment: class Role extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
  'role_name'
 ];

    public function employees()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class, 'role_employee');
    }
}